# Rename a Collection using Python?

Tags: python, collections

Is there a way to access a collection's name other than through bpy.context so it can be renamed?

Answer (score 4):

**Collections are ID objects**

In blender any ID object is stored in `bpy.data`  Objects in `bpy.data.objects` meshes in `bpy.data.meshes` collections in `bpy.data.collections` etc etc

To rename a collection named "Bob" to "Frank"

```
import bpy

col = bpy.data.collections.get("Bob")
if col:
    col.name = "Frank"
```

Note if there is already a collection named "Frank" then numbers are appended "Frank.001"... as per unique naming convention.

Related

[How to rename objects with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/how-to-rename-objects-with-python)

Comment: Thank you, batFINGER. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:)

```py
import bpy

col_name = "Collection"
new_name = "My Collection"

# Find the collection by name
col = bpy.data.collections.get(col_name)

# Rename the collection
col.name = new_name

# Update the Outliner to reflect the change
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```